# Using latest java grammar in old android system?

Tags: android, java-8, compatibility

I'm trying to use lambda grammar in Android app.
but lambda came with java sdk 1.8

is this ok for me to use latest 1.8 java grammar in old Android device?
I am sure that old Android device doesn't have jre 1.8

isn't there compatibility issue?

Comment: Last I tried, lambdas didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android doesn't support Java 8 yet because it uses the Dalvik JVM instead of Oracle's. Unfortunately you can't use the brilliant features of Java 8 in Andoird (e.g. default interface implementation, lambdas, streams, method reference, functional programming API) but you can use Groovy and there is a plug-in called Retro lambda that you can install that will let you use lambdas in Java 7.